# Log4JLogger does not implement Log when deploying on websphere 8.5.01

Tags: java, log4j, websphere, websphere-8, apache-commons-logging

I am facing this problem when trying to deploy an EAR file to websphere 8.5.0.1. The EAR only contains on its dependencies

commons-logging-1.1.3.jar,
log4j-1.2.17.jar

and a single JSF page.
As a remark, in the classpath by default must be a common-loggins copy, so deleting the library is not an option. 
The problem ocurs when initiliazing the server provided myfaces library, which needs commons-logging. The stack trace is pasted at the bottom. The application and we module classloaders are setted as parent last.

Any help will be highly appreciated

```
An error occured while initializing MyFaces: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger does not implement Log
          org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger does not implement Log
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:272)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:414)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.<init>(Digester.java:308)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.<init>(DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.java:42)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.getUnmarshaller(DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.java:93)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.getStandardFacesConfig(DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.java:131)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.getFacesConfigData(DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.java:69)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:456)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:313)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:136)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:111)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1676)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:414)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1173)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:772)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2175)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:994)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1814)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger does not implement Log
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:525)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger does not implement Log
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:412)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: I think websphere provides common logging. Remove commons-logging and try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WAS leverages apache common logging for this reason using it in your EAR with Parent Last policy break the runtime consistency and you get that exception.

I suggest you to remove that jar from your application to use the WAS provided one.
For further details:
[Configuring applications to use Jakarta Commons Logging](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/ae/ttrb_classload_jcl.html)

Answer (score 1):

Could be that you have 2 versions of commons-logging jar on the classpath. Remove one of them.